# What is the assembly and namespace of AllowXRequestsEveryXSecondsAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application created with Visual Studio 2017. I've been trying to use the `AllowXRequestsEveryXSecondsAttribute` for a controller action, but I can't find the assembly and namespace where it is defined. Apparently, the attribute's class is not defined in .NET Core yet, but I'm using .NET Framework.

Does anybody know the assembly and namespace where the attribute's class is defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AllowXRequestsEveryXSecondsAttribute` is not part of .NET Framework nor .NET Core. It is actually comes from 3rd party outside Microsoft, particularly to showcase security best practices in .NET Framework.

Microsoft has clarified this in their ASP.NET Core github:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6836

The library itself is in the form of project template, and it is only for .NET Framework mainly for .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later. Therefore it is not advisable to use this for your .NET Core project.

FYI, this is the link of the github repo that contains the implementation, usage and sample is at:
https://github.com/johnstaveley/SecurityEssentials

Comment: I downloaded the library and built it. It worked as expected. Thank you very much.